# NOT NULL constraint failed asp.net EF

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

I'm getting this error when I try to run my application.

'NOT NULL constraint failed: Countries.CountryId'

This is my code:
My model:

```
public class Country : Item
{
    public Country() : base()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Images { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Region> Regions { get; set; }

}
```

My Region Model:

```
 public class Region : Item
{
    public Region() : base()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    public Int16 Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Images { get; set; }

    /* Foreign Keys */
    public Nullable<Int32> CountryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

}
```

My DBContext (also added the Region, because it has something to do with the FK I assume):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Country>(l =>
        {
           l.ToTable("Countries");
           l.HasKey(m => m.Id); 
           l.Property(m => m.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
           l.Property(m => m.Name).IsRequired().HasColumnType("nvarchar(64)");
           l.Property(m => m.Description).IsRequired().HasColumnType("nvarchar(999)");
           l.Property(m => m.Images).IsRequired().HasColumnType("nvarchar(999)");

        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Region>(l =>
        {
           l.ToTable("Regions");
           l.HasKey(m => m.Id); 
           l.Property(m => m.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
           l.Property(m => m.Name).IsRequired().HasColumnType("nvarchar(64)");
           l.Property(m => m.Description).IsRequired().HasColumnType("nvarchar(999)");
           l.Property(m => m.Images).IsRequired().HasColumnType("nvarchar(999)");

           /* One Country for many Regions */
           l.HasOne(m => m.Country)
           .WithMany(m => m.Regions)
           .HasForeignKey(m => m.CountryId);   

        });
```

My Seeder:

```
        private async Task<bool> CreateCountries() 
    {
        if(_context.Countries == null || _context.Countries.Count() == 0)
        {
            var random = new Random();

            _context.Countries.Add(new Country()
            {
                Name = "Belgium",
                Description = _randomTextService.GetRandomText(1, 5, 15, "p").Results,
                Images =  "/Images/String van Images.jpg"
            });

            _context.Countries.Add(new Country()
            {
                Name = "Nederland",
                Description = _randomTextService.GetRandomText(1, 5, 15, "p").Results,
                Images =  "/Images/String van Images.jpg"
            });

            if(await _context.SaveChangesAsync() == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The region seed:

```
        private async Task<bool> CreateRegions() 
    {
        if(_context.Regions == null || _context.Regions.Count() == 0)
        {
            var random = new Random();
            var countries = _context.Countries.AsEnumerable();

            _context.Regions.Add(new Region()
            {
                Name = "Gent-zuid",
                Description = _randomTextService.GetRandomText(1, 5, 15, "p").Results,
                Images =  "/Images/String van Images.jpg",
                Country = countries.ElementAt(random.Next(0, countries.Count() - 1))
            });

            _context.Regions.Add(new Region()
            {
                Name = "Gent-noord",
                Description = _randomTextService.GetRandomText(1, 5, 15, "p").Results,
                Images =  "/Images/String van Images.jpg",
                Country = countries.ElementAt(random.Next(0, countries.Count() - 1))
            });

            if(await _context.SaveChangesAsync() == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I call them in this order:

```
await CreateRoles();// 1. Create Roles
        await CreateUsers();// 2. Create Users
        await CreateCountries();//3. Create Countries
        await CreateRegions();// 4. Create Regions
```

What am I doing wrong? I know the CountryId can't be NULL, but it is?

Comment: I don't see any mapping information for `CountryId`.  I see `Id`, not `CountryId`.

Comment: have you tried updating your db using update-database?

Comment: @sstan perhaps the variable `CountryId` comes from the `Item` class he derives from? Include your `Item` class if that's the case please

Comment: @sstan perhaps the variable `CountryId` comes from the `Item` class he derives from? Include your `Item` class if that's the case please

Comment: The error is for `Region` seed I guess, please add the seed for region as well.

Comment: I have added the Region seeder too. I also updated my database, no result. Doesn't the mapping for CountryId happends automatically (because it's a Foreign Key)? So I don't have to define it?

Comment: The error has something to do with me not seeding the CountryId but the Country. Bur when I change it to Id:
`CountryId = countries.ElementAt(random.Next(0, countries.Count() - 1)).Id`
 it gives me the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string''. So I have to make it a string?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. The mistake I was making was:
Not adding my CountryId as a Nullable to my Region Model like this:

```
public Nullable<Int16> CountryId { get; set; }
```

Thank you for your help!